# Issue while implementing firebaseUi auth in a nextjs project ? [error : window is not defined]

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, next.js, firebaseui

I'm trying to setup firebase Auth into my nextjs project (it looks like the firebase documentation is not up-to-date via the release of the getAuth method).

While using firebaseUi (to get the automatic styling of the different auth providers), I get this error :

[image]

Here is the code (i'm just trying to render the firebaseUi component for now) :

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Firestore
const db = getFirestore(app);

// Initialize Firebase Authentication
const auth = getAuth(app);

export { db, auth }
```

Then in a template page for signin :

```js
import { NavBar } from '../components';
import { StyledFirebaseAuth } from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import { auth } from '../firebase/initFirebase';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
const firebaseui = require('firebaseui')


// // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(auth);

function Signup() {

    const firebaseUiConfig = {
            signInFlow: 'popup',
            signInSuccessUrl: '/',
            tosUrl: '/terms-of-service',
            privacyPolicyUrl: '/privacy-policy',
            signInOptions: [
                GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
            ]
        }
        
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={firebaseUiConfig} firebaseAuth={auth} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signup
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help, I don't understand what's going on :(

// EDIT //
I understand it has to deal with SSR. So I did try to dynamically import firebaseUi with next/dynamic. I don't get the error any longer but the page is now blank (just the navbar component renders). Is it because I am passing props inappropriately ?

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { NavBar } from '../components';
import { auth } from '../firebase/initFirebase';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';

const AuthComponent = dynamic(() => 
    import('react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth').then((mod) => mod.StyledFirebaseAuth)
)

function Signup() {

    const firebaseUiConfig = {
            // signInFlow: 'popup',
            signInSuccessUrl: '/',
            tosUrl: '/legal',
            privacyPolicyUrl: '/legal',
            signInOptions: [
                GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
            ]
        }
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <AuthComponent uiConfig={firebaseUiConfig} firebaseAuth={auth} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signup
```

Comment: You need to pass the [`ssr: false`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) option on the `next/dynamic` call to dynamically import to component on the client-side only.

Comment: Thanks Julio. I tried but not working. Nothing shows up on the page. I think the FirebaseUi integration is not mature for Nextjs. I opted for the customized solution instead..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea here to disable SSR on the page which used firebaseui.

This can be done in two steps.

1. Use firebase ui or any library which needs `window` keywork to work.

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from '@leafygreen-ui/modal';
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import 'firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css'


export default function AuthUi({open, setOpen}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Modal open={open} setOpen={setOpen}>
        // Modal Content goes here.
        // Signup widgets comes here
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

2. while importing the library, do something like this.

```
//__app.js
// import AuthUi from '../components/authUi'; >> Replace this by code below
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const AuthUi = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/authUi'),
  { ssr: false }
);
```

Now you would be able to use firebaseui without window error.